# PercentRelativeLayout margin_percent not working in some cases

Tags: android, layout

The xml below in Nougat is ignoring the marginRightPercent.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"       
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:layout_heightPercent="3.45%"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="5.07%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="2.85%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="6.13%"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/action_bar_notification"/>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I have other places in my app where it's not ignored, but those other places do not have layout_widthPercent. This works fine in 6.0, but I think it's a bug in 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_marginRight="1dp"` - it can be any value. You just have to add it and then such value like `app:layout_marginRightPercent` will work. I don't know why - from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) I deduce it should be working anyway.

And in new projects we use ConstraintLayout, as PercentRelativeLayout is deprecated since API 26